# Pandas error converting string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a string dataframe column to dates in pandas. However, I'm getting this error. I'm guessing the time zone is looking for EST, not ET. Is there a way to fix this?

```
ValueError: time data '07/15/2004 / 04:50PM ET' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y / %I:%M%p %Z' (match)
```

Thanks

Edit:
I did `df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('ET', 'EST')`
and it's still throwing the error. Must be something else, will continue looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a known issue, in which %Z does not match certain timezones (i.e. EST).  You can read about it here in the [bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue22377).

Comment: Thanks! I'll just use `df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and add the timezone back in after (since it's consistent for the entire column).